# How to maximize android widget size (width)?

Tags: android, android-layout, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

I try to create a widget which should occupy the entire width of the screen. But it always initially corresponding to **android:minWidth**.

Sure, I can set android:minWidth to 250 dp, but I want to stay the widget resizable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:minWidth="170dp" 
android:minHeight="40dp"   
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_4"
android:configure="test.WidgetConfigureActivity"
android:resizeMode="horizontal" 
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_4">

</appwidget-provider>
```

layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_padding"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@color/translucent_black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageCircleButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/widget_circle_w"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/strLevelIndicator"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/appwidget_text_level"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="@string/strWidgetDefLevel"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="clip_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/appwidget_text_map"
                android:textColor="#c9c9c9"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/strWidgetDefText" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/appwidget_text_trend"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/translucent_black_dark">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageXButton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/strX"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/appwidget_x"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_button_height"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using android:minResizeWidth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:minResizeWidth="170dp"
android:minWidth="250dp" 
android:minHeight="40dp"   
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_4"
android:configure="test.WidgetConfigureActivity"
android:resizeMode="horizontal" 
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget_4">

</appwidget-provider>
```

minResizeWidth is meant exactly for what you're trying to achieve, setting a minWidth but let the user resize it to an even smaller size.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I dont see properties android:width and android:height,besides setting the minWidth or height theses properties are a must and set the width to warp content(which u might me knowing) which will solve your purpose of resizing